# Spigot | ClassCastException cannot Cast as chest

Tags: java, exception, casting, minecraft, bukkit

why is is saying cannot cast the block as a chest? i created it before...

```
Could not pass event PlayerDeathEvent to FactionsCSN v1.0-SNAPSHOT
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.block.CraftBlock cannot be cast to org.bukkit.block.Chest
        at creepans.factions.dims.GhostDimListener.onPlayerDeath(GhostDimListener.java:43)
```

Here you see, first Set Type to Chest and then the block at the same position have to be a chest

```
world.getBlockAt(loc).setType(Material.CHEST);
Chest crate = (Chest) world.getBlockAt(loc);
```

Comment: Does CraftBlock inherit Chest? If not, you can't do this cast

Comment: i dont know, where can i see that?

Comment: Go to the class definition of CraftBlock and see if it extends Chest (which it evidently doesn't). Instead of casting, see if there's another method in the API to turn a CraftBlock into a Chest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the block **state** to `Chest`, not the block itself. Try `Chest crate = (Chest) world.getBlockAt(loc).getState();` instead.